# Remove form field from views with initial data

Tags: python, django

This is my view:

```
key = request.GET['key']
if key:
    tier_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Listing)
    add_form = ProductPermissionForm(initial={'tier_type': tier_type,
                                              'tier_id': Listing.objects.get(listing_number=key).id},)
    form = add_form.as_p()
return HttpResponse(form)
```

I want to remove a form field from this ProductPermissionForm.
Any ideas?
I tried with init but it resets the form and my initial data is lost!

This is my init:

```
def __init__(self, key=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProductPermissionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if key is not None:
        self.fields.pop('lock')
```

`lock` is my field name I want to remove

Comment: @Alasdair: please see the edit

Comment: Could you please show the definition of `ProductPermissionForm`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
def __init__(self, key=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProductPermissionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if key is not None:
        del self.fields['lock']
```

Comment: What do you mean 'resets'?  Did you see the field go away?

Comment: not eaxctly but form.is_valid() is false but with no errors

Comment: Your form is `unbounded` because you haven't passed any data to it. Unbounded form will always be False when  `is_valid` is called. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/